# Trying to prevent having to press Enter twice for I/O

Tags: java

I am having trouble trying to input an integer by pressing enter only ONCE, not TWICE.

I have also tried using scan.nextLine() after the second line.

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
    scan.close();
    System.out.println(choice);
```

Comment: Never close `System.in`.

Comment: @shmosel Why should I never close?

Comment: Because you won't be able to read user input again.

Comment: @shmosel This does not solve the problem

Comment: It was a comment.

Comment: There is no problem though. Your snippet works fine. Please post a [mcve].